# Non-static variable this when putting into a static map

Tags: java, static

I have a static HashMap to which I'm adding a new item like so:

```
public static void addSession(Session session) {
    if(!map.containsKey(session)){
        map.put(session, new SessionThread(session));
    }
}
```

SessionThread is declared locally like so:

```
public class SessionThread implements Runnable {
```

That `map.put` line has a compile error of `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`. What is causing the error? `this` is not referenced anywhere in that method, let alone any non-static members. Everything is either static or in the scope of the method.

Entire class...

```
package me.scratchjava;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.RemoteEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.Session;

/**
 * A class for managing websocket threads.
 * @author James Smyth <jimsmyth at datafascia.com>
 */
public class SessionManager {

    private static HashMap<Session, SessionThread> map = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Called whenever a new websocket is opened.
     * @param session 
     */
    public static void addSession(Session session) {
        if(!map.containsKey(session)){
            map.put(session, new SessionThread(session));
        }
    }

    public static void removeSession(Session session){
        if(map.containsKey(session)){
            map.remove(session);
        }
    }

    public static void sendData(Session session, byte[] bytes){
        if(map.containsKey(session)){
            map.get(session).send(bytes);
        }
    }

    public class SessionThread implements Runnable {
        private Session session;
        private boolean alive = true;
        private final LinkedList<byte[]> messageQueue = new LinkedList<>();

        public SessionThread(Session session){

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (alive) {
                if(Thread.interrupted()){
                    alive = false;
                    return;
                }

                synchronized (messageQueue) {
                    while(!messageQueue.isEmpty()){
                        byte[] msg = messageQueue.poll();
                        try {
                            session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(ByteBuffer.wrap(msg));
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(SessionManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void send(byte[] bytes) {
            synchronized (messageQueue) {
                messageQueue.add(bytes);
            }
        }

        public void kill(){
            alive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `map` declared? Show us the full compiler error.

Comment: private static HashMap<Session, SessionThread> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: org/datafascia/hydrant/server/SessionManager.java:[32,30] non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
1 error

Comment: How are `Session` and `SessionThread` declared?  Are they inner classes?

Comment: The question appears to be incomplete and so far misleading.

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are correct.

Comment: The entire class is here: http://pastebin.com/xxk0qBAB Try compiling it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `SessionThread` inner class is *not* static. That means the compiler generates a constructor to capture the value of `this`, the enclosing class. Since you're trying to create a new SessionThread in a static method, there is no `this` to capture. Make the class static.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Edit**

@directedition: SessionThread should be a static class.  Actually it should be a stand alone interface and class.

Comment: As mentioned at the start of the post, the map is static.

Comment: @directedition: until you show me the code, I frankly don't believe it until I see it. Please improve your question.

Comment: I should probably note that I'm using JDK8.

Comment: @directedition: please show the pertinent code in your question, not in a link. All should be able to review it and understand it.

Comment: The pertinent code is all in the question. Should I paste the entire .java file here?

Comment: @directedition: SessionThread should be a static class. Actually it should be a stand alone interface and class.

Comment: @directedition: hell no it's not. You don't have your inner class in the code you've posted!

Comment: Ahh, you are quite correct. An oddly deceptive error message for it.

Comment: @directedition: fix your question please. So I can remove my down vote. As posted it is still unanswerable and links don't count.